# Manipulating variables?

Tags: java

This programs adds values to a variable called money, which is initially set at 0, depending on what number is generated (prime, composite, square, or other).

I know if I have two numbers that are the same then it produces 0 all the time.
I am almost certain the multiples of 11, the composites, and the primes are always producing correct values.

For example, when I get the random numbers of 52 (composite), 73 (prime), 13 (prime), 56 (composite), 64 (square), and 23 (prime) I get a returned value of 708, but the answer is supposed to be 716.

52 + 100 + 100 +56 = 308 * 2 = 616 + 100 = 716

There must be something wrong with the loop for the squares, can anybody see anything that might not produce a correct result? Thank you!

```
//importing popup window and random numbers
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import java.util.Random;

public class HarvestProject3
{//open HarvestProject3 class

 public static void main (String [] args)
 {//open main

  //Start screen
  String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello, what is your name?");
  System.out.println(name);

  String charity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ok, " + name + " , instead of collecting candy on October 31st, you will be collecting money for your own charity. \n Now, please tell me what is the name of your charity that you would like to collect the money for?");
  System.out.println(charity);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Great! I am going to pick 6 randomly selected houses (by house number) for you to stop by to collect money for " + charity + ". \n \n Pleas be aware that it is Halloween night, you don't what can happen, expecially on a street called Crazy Street.");

  //Random Numbers
  Random rangen = new Random();
  int HouseNumber1 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;
  int HouseNumber2 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;
  int HouseNumber3 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;
  int HouseNumber4 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;
  int HouseNumber5 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;
  int HouseNumber6 = rangen.nextInt(98) + 3;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok, " + name + ", you are going to be stopping at houses, " + HouseNumber1 + ", " + HouseNumber2 + ", " + HouseNumber3 + ", " + HouseNumber4 + ", " + HouseNumber5 + ", and " + HouseNumber6);

  if (HouseNumber1 == HouseNumber2 || HouseNumber1 == HouseNumber3 || HouseNumber1 == HouseNumber4 || HouseNumber1 == HouseNumber5 || HouseNumber1 == HouseNumber6 || HouseNumber2 == HouseNumber3 || HouseNumber2 == HouseNumber4 || HouseNumber2 == HouseNumber5 || HouseNumber2 == HouseNumber6 || HouseNumber3 == HouseNumber4 || HouseNumber3 == HouseNumber5 || HouseNumber3 == HouseNumber6 || HouseNumber4 == HouseNumber5 || HouseNumber4 == HouseNumber6 || HouseNumber5 == HouseNumber6)
  {//open if
     int NoMoney = 0;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have asked for money from the same house again... \n \n A nasty old lady opens the door and screams, Give me your money!, Get out of my house! and chased you off Crazy Street and stole all of your money. \n \n You collected " + NoMoney + " dollars.");
     System.exit(0);        

  }//close if

  int money = 0;    

//Looping for primes
  int[] PrimeArray = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97};

  for (int i : PrimeArray)
  {//open enhanced for loop

     if (HouseNumber1 == i || HouseNumber2 == i || HouseNumber3 == i || HouseNumber4 == i || HouseNumber5 == i || HouseNumber6 == i)
     {//open if

        money += 100;

     }//close if            
  }//close enhanced for loop

//Looping for squares 
  int SquareArray[] = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100};

  for (int i : SquareArray)
  {//open enhanced for loop

     if (HouseNumber1 == i || HouseNumber2 == i || HouseNumber3 == i || HouseNumber4 == i || HouseNumber5 == i || HouseNumber6 == i)
     {//open if

        money *= 2;

     }//close if
  }//close enhanced for loop

//Looping for multiples of 11 (not including 11 because it is prime)
  int ElevenArray[] = {22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99};
  for (int i : ElevenArray)
  {//open enhanced for loop

     if (HouseNumber1 == i || HouseNumber2 == i || HouseNumber3 == i || HouseNumber4 == i || HouseNumber5 == i || HouseNumber6 == i)
     {//open if

        money -= 5;

     }//close if
   }//close enhanced for loop

     //Looping for some composites
  int SomeCompositesArray[] = {6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 20, 21, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 46, 48, 50, 51, 52, 54, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98};

  for (int i : SomeCompositesArray)
  {//open enhanced for loop

     if (HouseNumber1 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber1;

     }//close if

     if (HouseNumber2 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber2;

     }//close if

     if (HouseNumber3 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber3;

     }//close if

     if (HouseNumber4 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber4;

     }//close if

     if (HouseNumber5 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber5;

     }//close if

     if (HouseNumber6 == i)
     {//open if

        money += HouseNumber6;

     }//close if
  }//close enhanced for loop
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You collected " + money + " dollars for " + charity + "!!!");
  }//close main
}//close HarvestProject3 class
```

Comment: if you simply want double money why can't you simply do `money *= 2;` inside your `if(HouseNumber1 == i){..}` instead of adding the `DoubleMoney`? Do the same where you need DoubleMoney.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I will try it right now. Thank you! I will let you know if it works or not soon.

Comment: it is not computing right whenever there is a square. I know it is doubling the number but something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you wanted, but couldn't you do just this:

```
money *= 2;
```

or this

```
money += money;
```

instead of this

```
money += DoubledMoney;
```

**By the way**: Instead of doing 100x ifs, why don't you just put more than condition in an if, like this:

```
if(HouseNumber1 == i || HouseNumber2 == i || HouseNumberX == i){
 // do the work
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get your point about the ifs, I did do that initially and did not realize that I could easily do it again.

hagubear mentioned the money *= 2 above you which I did change,

If you run the program I am not getting the answers I want sometimes, I think I am going to have go through each line to make sure I know what it is doing, not just what I think it is doing. It is going to be a very tedious process.

Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten down a bunch of your code to mitigate the chance of errors of repeating in so many places. I also changed the money *= 2; which should be what you wanted. Hope i didn't mess any of your stuff up in this long overdone process heh. P.S. haven't tested this in an IDE

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello, what is your name?");
        System.out.println(name);

        String charity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ok, " + name + " , instead of collecting     candy on October 31st, you will be collecting money for your own charity. \n Now, please tell me what is the name of your charity that you would like to collect the money for?");
        System.out.println(charity);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Great! I am going to pick 6 randomly selected houses (by house number) for you to stop by to collect money for " + charity + ". \n \n Pleas be aware that it is Halloween night, you don't what can happen, expecially on a street called Crazy Street.");

        Random rangen = new Random();

        int[] houseNumbers = new int[6];
        for(int i = 0; i < houseNumbers.length; i ++){
            houseNumbers[i] = rangen.nextInt(98) + 2;
        }

        String housesString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < houseNumbers.length; i ++){
            housesString += (i != houseNumbers.length - 1) ? houseNumbers[i] + ", " : " and " + houseNumbers[i];
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok, " + name + ", you are going to be stopping at houses, " + housesString);

        Set<Integer> lump = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : houseNumbers){
            if (lump.contains(i)){
                int NoMoney = 0;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have asked for money from the same house again... \n A mean old lady opens the door and screams, Give me your money!, Get out of my house! and chased you off Crazy Street and stole all of your money. \n You collected " + NoMoney + " dollars");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            lump.add(i);
        }

        int money = 0;    

        int[] PrimeArray = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97};

        for (int i : PrimeArray)
        {
            for(int j : houseNumbers){
                if(j == i)
                    money += 100;
            }
        }

        int SquareArray[] = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100};
        for (int i : SquareArray)
        {
            for(int j : houseNumbers){
                if(j == i)
                    money *= 2;
            }
        }

        int ElevenArray[] = {22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99};
        for (int i : ElevenArray)
        {
            for(int j : houseNumbers){
                if(j == i)
                    money -= 5;
            }
        }

        int SomeCompositesArray[] = {6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 20, 21, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 46, 48, 50, 51, 52, 54, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98};
        for (int i : SomeCompositesArray)
        {
            for(int j : houseNumbers){
                if(j == i)
                    money += j;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You collected " + money + " dollars for " + charity + "!!!");
```

Comment: That is very impressive, thank you. I will test it right now.

Comment: Can you fix this line of code? Set<Integer> lump = new HashSet<Integer>();

Comment: It cannot find the symbol for Set or HashSet. Do I need to save the file a specific name?